# CellForRowAtIndexPath method not being called in storyboards

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I am using `storyboards` for my app.In that I have a `UITableViewController` class.I am loading the `UITableView` from the data coming from the webservice. The issue is that the data is coming but is not geting populated in `UITableView`. On Decoding I found out that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not getting called.

Do we need to connect the `datasource` and `delegate` in `storyboard` as it was done in separate `xibs` before `storyboard`. And if so, where to connect the `datasource` and `delegate` methods as there is **NO** `Filesowner` in `storyboard`.

I am stuck up with this issue and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a table view controller into a storyboard, it usually has the table view's dataSource and delegate already set up correctly.  If yours turn out to be connected OK, the other possibility is that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning zero.

Comment: :- I am seeing no connections in xib present in the storyboard for datasource and delegate.So how does the controller know that if it is set up correctly.NumberofRows is non zero in my case

Comment: Select the table view in the storyboard and click on the Connections Inspector.  It shows whether the delegate and dataSource are connected.  If not, you can click and drag from there to the view controller, either its visual image or its name in the list of scenes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `UITableViewController`, then you need to make the `numberOfSections:tableView:` data source method returns 1 instead of the default return of 0.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1 // Default is 0, should be greater than 0
}
```